# How to render HeroCard in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, bots

I have created a `WPF` application that is connecting to a bot build with bot framework. I am not having any issues to display adaptive cards but the bot has few `HeroCards` which when I render it with adaptive card, few actions are not showing as it's "exceeding the limit".

Can I render `HeroCard` in `WPF`? I didn't see something in MS docs.

Note
A HeroCard is a bot class:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.connector.herocard?view=botbuilder-dotnet-3.0

Comment: Question is not clear. What are hero cards? What do you mean by "Exceeing the limit"? What is the ms doc you're referring to? You will need to provide a [Minimal, Reproducable Code Sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your issue.

Comment: A HeroCard is a bot class. I've edited the question to make this clear.

Comment: I don't think there's a way you can just display a HeroCard in wpf directly. You'd probably have to translate one into viewmodels. It's a fairly rich object containing eg a list of cardimage. You'd need to translate whatever a  cardimage is into something wpf can understand.

Comment: "Exceeing the limit" means exceeding the number of actions that adaptive card class can display.